Strange behaviour of Firefox PDF viewer
I am not sure if this question is on-topic, but I suspect the problem might be connected to Linux (since I've never had this problem in Firefox on any other device). I am using Ubuntu 23.10.1 with KDE Plasma desktop environment. Since recently I've been experiencing the following problem with Firfox document viewer: after a period of inactivity, PDFs become unreadable, and seem to cumulate everything that was displayed on screen (see screenshot). 
Ctrl + F5 does not help, and neither does closing the window and opening a new one with a link to the file. KDE Document Viewer displays the same file correctly.

Try perhaps to reinstall Firefox. Save bookmarks etc.

Rather than use the SNAP version of Firefox, you might try installing the latest stable version from Mozilla PPA. See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/ and  https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa . Using that latest stable build in Ubuntu (20.04 LTS), I do not see that issue. If that helps, please let me know and I'll expand this to an answer.

I have never used the SNAP itself, Firefox came pre-installed in Ubuntu 23.10.1

Have you found a solution to this problem? I’m facing the same issue on Ubuntu 24.04. It goes away if I restart Firefox. I might try the PPA solution (note that Firefox is installed as a snap by default now). Also, what is your GPU? Are you using X.org or Wayland? (I’m using X.org on an RTX 3070)

I think the multiple duplicate images of the total screen probably point to a driver issue. Might try disabling hardware acceleration or similar

I had the same issues for months now and no hint helped ... but surprisingly the problem went away after an upgrade to FireFox 127.

Same problem here. Ubuntu 23.10 with nvidia drivers (GTX 1660). IMO the issue is related to the Nvidia drivers.

@DrMoishePippik I switched to the PPA version (currently v129.0) and it did not fix the problem, but at least now I can open PDF’s externally with more ease – I could never get the Snap version to open downloaded files.

I think it’s pretty clear now that the issue is Nvidia-specific. I have seen more people report it with Nvidia GPUs, and there is actually Bugzilla ticket 1904707 and a possible workaround described on Arch’s wiki. Might be worth testing on older drivers.

Firefox 129+ has disabled HW acceleration for PDF’s. You can also toggle it on or off with pdfjs.enableHWA in about:config (should be false by default as apparently PDF’s don’t benefit from it).
I haven’t seen this issue in a while (but I also switched to the PPA version), except for sites that use PDF.js directly. As a workaround for those sites, or Google Sheets, or if you are using an older version of Firefox, you can turn off gfx.canvas.accelerated (also in about:config) which disables hardware acceleration for all canvas.
Also note that restarting Firefox usually fixes the issue temporarily.
Here is a list of relevant bugs:

1904707 - Internal pdf viewer unusable
1910395 - PDF viewer flickering and "smearing" text around
1907828 - accelerated canvas (PDF viewer or Google Sheets) shows wrong content on Linux Nvidia


I found a solution to this problem here: https://www.linux.org/threads/im-having-issues-rendering-pdf-files-in-firefox.50018/
Weridly the solution seems very easy:

Go to Settings -> General -> Application
Look for Portable Document File (PDF) and set the open with to "systems default"
Restart Firefox
Go back to settings and change it back to "Open in Firefox"

It has fixed it for me! (Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04)

Restarting Firefox temporarily fixes the problem…

I am experiencing the same or very very similar with openSUSE Tumbleweed. Firefox Version 126.01.1 here. To attempt workaround > setting browser.display.use_document_fonts to 0 in about:config
Some websites font rendering is a bit incorrect then though.
This is a online pdf on the machine here failing to display.

Using KDE6 with X11. Nvidia Quadro K600 GPU.
Restarting Firefox did allow for the opened tab containing the PDF to be displayed correctly.

This does not fix the issue for me, and it’s actually unclear to me whether it fixed it for you (since you post a screenshot of the issue). If it was intended to report the workaround as non-working, you should post it as a comment instead (which you will be able to do once you have more rep). Side note, this config value is available as a checkbox in the preferences, under the advanced font parameters.

Ok thanks for your help. That did not fix the issue see above. I could not comment so I created the post. I did not know the config was available under advanced font parameters. PDF files are opening without the previous problems on the machine now (more testing needed). I see your links above.

Do you mean that you don’t have the issue right now, or you didn’t have it since you changed that font setting? Note that the issue goes away when you restart the browser. In fact, it seems to be triggered randomly after the computer goes to sleep.

The issue seems cleared up here by using this workaround (I am still testing). https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1904707
